# Calculate weights for grouped data in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to calculate portfolio weights with a pandas dataframe. Here is some dummy data for an example:

```
df1 = DataFrame({'name' : ['ann','bob']*3}).sort('name').reset_index(drop=True)
df2 = DataFrame({'stock' : list('ABC')*2})
df3 = DataFrame({'val': np.random.randint(10,100,6)})
df = pd.concat([df1, df2, df3], axis=1)
```

[image]

Each person owns 3 stocks with a value `val`. We can calculate portfolio weights like this:

```
df.groupby('name').apply(lambda x: x.val/(x.val).sum())
```

which gives this:

[image]

If I want to add a column `wgt` to `df` I need to merge this result back to `df` on `name` and `index`. This seems rather clunky.

Is there a way to do this in one step? Or what is the way to do this that best utilizes pandas features?

Answer (score 7):

Use `transform`, this will return a series with an index aligned to your original df:

```
In [114]:
df['wgt'] = df.groupby('name')['val'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())
df

Out[114]:
  name stock  val       wgt
0  ann     A   18  0.131387
1  ann     B   43  0.313869
2  ann     C   76  0.554745
3  bob     A   16  0.142857
4  bob     B   44  0.392857
5  bob     C   52  0.464286
```

Comment: Ah, so you have to give `transform` a Series. I tried this but passed the whole dataframe, and was getting a broadcast error.

Comment: suppose rather than `val` I had `shares` and `price`, so I need to multiply them before doing the weight. `transform` can't handle this, right? Is there still an elegant solution in that case?

Comment: Sorry you're asking how to use 2 columns in a groupby/transform?

Comment: Yes. Suppose rather than `val`, I just had `shares` and `price` so I need to pass `df.groupby('name')` and have the lambda function something like `lambda x: (x.shares*x.price)/((x.shares*x.price).sum())`

Comment: You may have to perform the multiplication and add this as a new column prior to performing the groupby as the shape and alignment gets fussy